# Feedback modal with star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a feedback modal in which I have ratings which simply using +,_ signs for various types of ratings - Poor, fair, good, very good, Excellent. Now I have to move this design into star rating. My modal is bootstrap modal.
Is there a way I can move my code to star rating? I have no idea how to implement the star animation for star rating.

My current code for feedback modal is below

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="message" style="text-align: center; color: green;"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <span id="updatecapacitymodalerrortext" style="color:red"></span> 
                                      </div>
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                        </br>
                                        &nbsp;<label>Your Name : </label>
                                        </br><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" style="width:50px;"  id="capacity_txt_modal" />
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <br/>

<div class="feedback">
      <div class="feedbackCl" >
      <input id="overall_0" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o1-l">
      <label for="overall_0" class="labelClass">
        <span class="sight">— —</span>
        <span class="screen_reader" id="o1-l">Poor</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="feedbackCl">
      <input id="overall_1" name="overall"  id="overall" type="radio" value="2" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o2-l">
      <label for="overall_1" class="labelClass">
        <span class="sight">—</span>
        <span class="screen_reader" id="o2-l">Fair</span>
      </label>

    </div>
    <div class="feedbackCl">
      <input id="overall_2" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="3" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o3-l">
      <label for="overall_2" class="labelClass">
        <span class="sight">+ —</span>
        <span class="screen_reader" id="o3-l">Good</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div class="feedbackCl">
      <input id="overall_3" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="4" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o4-l">
      <label for="overall_3" class="labelClass">
        <span class="sight">+</span>
        <span class="screen_reader" id="o4-l">Very Good</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="feedbackCl">
      <input id="overall_4" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="5" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o5-l">
      <label for="overall_4" class="labelClass">
        <span class="sight">+ +</span>
        <span class="screen_reader" id="o5-l">Excellent</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <label for="input-1" class="control-label">Rate This</label>
    <input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1">
    <button type="button" id="updateCapacityBtn" class="btn btn-info ">Save</button>
    <button type="button" id="capacityModalClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I believe you need to implement some jquery rating plugin to do it?

Comment: Yes. I think so. any plugIns suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, i have added demo jQuery rating plugin to your feedback modal popup, Hope this works

**Try out this code:**

```js
$(function () {
     
      $("#rateYo").rateYo({
     
        onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
           rating = Math.ceil(rating);
           $('#rating_input').val(rating);//setting up rating value to hidden field
           alert("Rating is set to: " + rating);
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">


<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="message" style="text-align: center; color: green;"></div>
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                <span id="updatecapacitymodalerrortext" style="color:red"></span> 
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" >
                                    <label style="display:inline-block" class="col-md-4">Your Name : </label>
                                    <div style="display:inline-block;" class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="capacity_txt_modal" />
                                    </div>

</div>
<label style="display:inline-block;" for="input-1" class="control-label">Rate This</label>
<div style="display:inline-block;" id="rateYo"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating_input"/>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="updateCapacityBtn" class="btn btn-info ">Save</button>
<button type="button" id="capacityModalClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is the way I want, but is it possible to capture the star rating value without decimals? I need star rating to be 1,2,3,4,5 only.Thank u for sharing this.

Comment: Ok, updated code with JS `Math.ceil()`  function to round up decimal values

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve your labels i used a different [plug in](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating). I added only the labels to your input field:

```
data-star-captions='["Not Rated", "Poor", "Fair","Good","Very Good","Excellent"]'
```

The snippet:

```js
$('#myModal1').modal('show');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/css/star-rating.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="message" style="text-align: center; color: green;"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span id="updatecapacitymodalerrortext" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    </br>
                    &nbsp;<label>Your Name : </label>
                    </br><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="capacity_txt_modal"/>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="feedback">
                        <label for="input-1" class="control-label">Rate This</label>
                        <input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" data-min="0" data-max="5"
                               data-step="1" data-star-captions='["Not Rated", "Poor", "Fair","Good","Very Good","Excellent"]'>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="updateCapacityBtn" class="btn btn-info ">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" id="capacityModalClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```